# Can I Define my own form markup and map with to the form generated using Gravity Form (wordpress plugin)?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity

I am using Gravity Forms in my wordpress site. I want a way in which I can define my own form markup and map it to the form generated using Gravity Forms so when someone submits the form it mails to the email id defined in gravity form and also adds to the gravity form section in wordpress backend.

Comment: would you like to do it using jquery?

Comment: Ya I would love if you give a js/jQuery based solution.Thank You

Comment: unfortunately it wouldnt add a gravity form section in your wp backend

Comment: Why change the form markup?  If you want it to look different, just style it.  Changing the markup sort of defeats the purpose of using a plugin to generate the form.

Comment: @AndyWarren Hmm ya that is true. But is there a way to get plceholder support for form fields in gravity forms .

Comment: Yes there is.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will allow for placeholder text in text inputs for Gravity Forms.

[Gravity Forms Placeholder Text](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-gravity-forms/)

You may have to delete the very first `<?php` from this block of code.  You'll then have an additional "Placeholder" input in the Gravity Forms editor for text inputs.

Comment: Since this was down voted a year and a half after the answer, I'll post a new suggestions.  Try this plugin, it works great: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-placeholders/

Comment: Suggested plugin works like a charm. Just added the gplaceholder class to the form element and saved. Boom! Thanks Andy!

Comment: Yep, glad I could help.  Just an FYI,  GF will soon be having built in placeholder support.  Not sure when, but I saw a test build screenshot from Carl Hancock (GF Founder).