# Add Placeholders to Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, html, wordpress, placeholder, gravity

Is there a way to add HTML5 placeholders to Gravity Forms? I've tried a number of plugins, but none of them appear to work.

Gravity Forms: http://www.gravityforms.com/
One Plugin (that doesn't work): http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-auto-placeholders/changelog/
Another: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-placeholders/

Comment: Yes, please see my answer on the following thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341521/can-i-define-my-own-form-markup-and-map-with-to-the-form-generated-using-gravity/13366627#13366627

Comment: After trying this, I get the error "jQuery is not defined" in Chrome. jQuery's included at the bottom of the page, not sure what the issue is. URL: http://www.olympicloans.com/users/?page_id=10

Comment: @Rev you try to use jQuery before it's instantiated in the page.

Comment: Thought I had tried that before, but after trying again it does work. Thanks.

Comment: You're getting this due to the jQuery no conflict issue.  Remove your copy of jQuery as it is already packaged with WordPress.  Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please see my answer on the following thread:  [Can I Define my own form markup and map with to the form generated using Gravity Form (wordpress plugin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341521/can-i-define-my-own-form-markup-and-map-with-to-the-form-generated-using-gravity/13366627#13366627)

This will add an extra field for text inputs that will allow for placeholder text.  Very easy to implement, basically adding some code to the functions.php file.